# connection error from aws fargete to gcp bigquery by using Workload Identity

Tags: google-bigquery, aws-fargate, workload-identity

I used Workload Identity from AWS EC2 to GCP Bigquery by using assigned role on EC2, and it worked fine.

However when I use Workload Identity from AWS Fargete to GCP Bigquery by using fargate task role, it does not work.

How should I set up the Workload Identity on this case?

I used the libraries below.

```
implementation(platform("com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:20.9.0"))
implementation("com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery")
```

Stacktrace has messages below

```
com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Failed to retrieve AWS IAM role.
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.translate(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:115) ~[google-cloud-bigquery-1.137.1.jar!/:1.137.1]
…
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve AWS IAM role.
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.AwsCredentials.retrieveResource(AwsCredentials.java:217) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.26.0.jar!/:na]
…
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.getDataset(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:126) ~[google-cloud-bigquery-1.137.1.jar!/:1.137.1]
    ... 113 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Invalid argument (connect failed)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.AwsCredentials.retrieveResource(AwsCredentials.java:214) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.26.0.jar!/:na]
    ... 132 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar issue with Google Cloud Storage (GCS).

As Peter mentioned, retrieving the credentials on an AWS Farage task is not the same as if the code is running on an EC2 instance, therefore Google SDK fails to compose the correct AWS credentials for exchange with Google Workload Identity Federation.

I came up with a workaround that saved the trouble of editing core files in "../google/auth/aws.py" by doing 2 things:

1. Get session credentials with boto3

```
import boto3

task_credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials().get_frozen_credentials()
```

2. Set the relevant environment variables

```
from google.auth.aws import environment_vars

os.environ[environment_vars.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID] = task_credentials.access_key
os.environ[environment_vars.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY] = task_credentials.secret_key
os.environ[environment_vars.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN] = task_credentials.token
```

**Explanation:**
I am using Python3.9 with boto3 and google-cloud==2.4.0, however it should work for other versions of google SDK if the following code is in the function "_get_security_credentials" under the class "Credentials" in "google.auth.aws" package:

```
        # Check environment variables for permanent credentials first.
        # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html
        env_aws_access_key_id = os.environ.get(environment_vars.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
        env_aws_secret_access_key = os.environ.get(
            environment_vars.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
        )
        # This is normally not available for permanent credentials.
        env_aws_session_token = os.environ.get(environment_vars.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN)
        if env_aws_access_key_id and env_aws_secret_access_key:
            return {
                "access_key_id": env_aws_access_key_id,
                "secret_access_key": env_aws_secret_access_key,
                "security_token": env_aws_session_token,
            }
```

**Caveat:**
When running code inside an ECS task the credentials that are being used are temporary (ECS assumes the task's role), therefore you can't generate temporary credentials via AWS STS as it is usually recommended.
Why is it a problem? Well since a task is running with temporary credentials it is subjected to expire & refresh. In order to solve that you can set up a background function that will do the operation again every 5 minutes or so (Haven't faced a problem where the temporary credentials expired).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but for Python code, anyway I think it should be the same.
You're getting this as getting the AWS IAM role at AWS Fargate is different from AWS EC2, where EC2 you can get them from instance metadata, as shown here:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/s3access
```

While in AWS Faragte:

```
curl 169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI
```

So to get around that, the following need to be done:

1. Change GCP Workload Identity Federation Credential file content [wif_cred_file] as the following:

```
    wif_cred_file["credential_source"]["url"]=f"http://169.254.170.2{AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI}"
```

2. In the "python3.8/site-packages/google/auth/**aws.py**" file in the library [Try to find the similar file in Java], I've updated this code as the following:
3. Comment this line:
   `# role_name = self._get_metadata_role_name(request)`
4. Remove `role_name` from `_get_metadata_security_credentials` function args.

Or if you like, you may change step 1 at the **aws.py** file, both ways should be fine.

And that should be it.